# HTML5 <audio> element refusing to work on reload

Tags: javascript, html, audio

In my web project I have a page with an empty div. The contents of that div get reloaded whenever a button is clicked, which carries out a `$('#BandContainer').load("StartLoading.php");` whenever it is clicked. this reloads anything in the `#BandContainer` div tag.

In the contents of that div tag, there will always be an  element, which plays the same file. However I have noticed that it often fails to work:

- Whenever I reload the `#BandContainer` div without playing the audio file first, it will not work until I clear out mycookies and start again,
- However when I play the audio file *then* reload the `#BandContainer` div, it works fine.

Is there any cause for this? It is happening on the latest version of Chrome.